# Find all URLs with a specific anchor text Python / BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anchor

I am trying to get all URLs with the anchor text `Personal Website`. Here is an example of the HTML I am talking about.

```
<a href="http://example.com" class>Personal website</a>
```

Right now, I am trying to do so with this:

```
for link in bio_link_list:
    site = soup.find_all("a", href = True, text = "Personal Website")
    site_list.append(site)
```

Where `bio_link_list` is just a list of links I am scraping. But this just returns an empty list. For clarification, I want a list of URLs that have that specific anchor text.

Comment: What's the website you're scraping?

Comment: I am scraping https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form. I want to go through each link in the "name" column and get the personal website link.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using the https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form or the link from the Name on the page in the bio_link_list? My proposed solution mentioned below is assuming that you have the bio links in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're code is not working is that no anchor is of `class Perosnal website`. But after inspecting the source code, you can easily grab all `a` elements and filter them for `bio` string.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").find_all("a")
bio_links = [a['href'] for a in soup if "bio" in a['href']]

print(f"Found {len(bio_links)} bio links:")
print(bio_links)
```

Output:

```
Found 465 bio links
['https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/bio/viral-acharya', 'https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/bio/allen-adamson', 'https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/bio/beril-afsar',...]
```

This yields `465` results, which is exactly the same value as on the page under `<div class="results">465 results</div>`.

EDIT: I initially misunderstood your question, but here's a way to get personal web sites from the bio urls.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").find_all("a")
bio_links = [a['href'] for a in soup if "bio" in a['href']]

personal_sites = []
for link in bio_links:
    print(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    personal_sites.extend(
        [
            a["href"] for a in soup.find_all("a") 
            if a.getText() == "Personal website"
        ]
    )

print(personal_sites)
```

Output:

```
['http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~sternfin/vacharya/public_html/~vacharya.htm', 'http://brandsimple.com/about-allen-adamson/', 'http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~sternfin/talbanese/', 'http://www.stern.nyu.edu/~ealtman', ...]
```

Finally, you can speed things up using the `lxml` module and Xpath to get the personal website links.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form"
ps_xpath = '//*[@id="bio-details"]/div[2]/p[3]/a[2]/@href'


def get_page(url: str):
    return requests.get(url).content


def get_personal_site(url: str):
    ps = html.fromstring(get_page(url)).xpath(ps_xpath)
    return next(iter(ps), None)


def scrape_sites(bio_links: list):
    return [get_personal_site(link) for link in bio_links]


soup = BeautifulSoup(get_page(url), "html.parser").find_all("a")
links = [a['href'] for a in soup if "bio" in a['href']]

print(scrape_sites(links))
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did to find their NYU webpages, but I wanted to find their personal webpages that were on that list of NYU webpages. Sorry if I was unclear. Thank you nonetheless, your method was much faster than mine!

Answer (score 1):

I guess a simple if condition will do the trick

```
for url in all_bio_links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    links=[]
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if a.text=="Personal website":
            links.append(a['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to ignore the `link` variable. Are you sure you don't want to make a request first to `link` and then scrape the resulting HTML?
Either way, try this.

```py
urls = [tag["href"] for tag in soup.find_all("a") if tag.getText() == "Personal Website" and tag["href"]]
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! For some reason it returned the "Personal website" text along with a bunch of empty entries, but I should be able to deal with that.

Comment: If you need more help, I will gladly take part considering you will provide more information about the entries on your side.
More than that, if this helped you consider upvoting/marking as accepted answer, since some people here seem to downvote the answers that are not theirs. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

### This answer assumes that you have the profile URLs in the bio_link_list. If not, there is a way to scrape the information using an alteration of the code below before assessing the profile pages.

You can try this solution. The text file List.txt is the source of urls. One per line. This will also write all the output to a csv file for later use.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
from lxml.html import parse
import re

dataList = []

New_date_id = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

with open('List.txt') as urlList:
    urls = (line for line in urlList)

    for url in urls:
        site = urlopen(url)   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml")
        for item in soup.findAll('a', text = re.compile('Personal website')):
            newItem = (item.get ('href'))
            dataList.append(newItem)
            
#with open(date_id + 'data.txt', "w", encoding='utf-8') as fhandle:
with open(New_date_id + "_"+ 'data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    for line in dataList:       
        csv_file.write(f'{line} \n')
```